# Bench Supply Amps - 4AA Batteries

Tags: power, batteries

I have a battery powered device that runs from 4 AA batteries. Whilst testing, I am wanting to power it from an adjustable bench power supply.

How can I work out what amperage to set my bench supply at? Do AA batteries have a standard amp rating? There is nothing mentioned on the battery itself.

Comment: we have no idea what your bench supply is - unless you deliver a much more detailed description of the device, we can't help you.

Comment: Typically you would set the *voltage* of your bench supply.  If you set the amperage, it would be as a fault limit - your supply would only switch to current limit mode if something goes wrong.  With some notable exceptions (power tools, RC models, etc) things running off AA batteries are likely to draw less than say 500 milliamps.

Comment: So if I set the amperage of the bench PSU to 5 amps (for example) it is just a maximum limit, the device will draw as much as it needs up to the limit?

Comment: Yes, but if you have an adjustable limit, you might as well turn it down to a healthy margin over a likely value.

Comment: Thanks Chris, explained perfectly. Can you create an answer and I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: Your battery-powered device may (for short time periods) require a current surge. A motor is an example. Audio may require surge current too. You'd first set your supply to 6V. If you see voltage dip during a surge, set current higher so that voltage remains constant 6V.

Comment: @glen_geek, with a bench supply you won't see much of voltage dip, since the supply would have a very low ESR.

Comment: @AliChen I'm assuming that a bench supply has a variable control that could be used as a "current-limit". A current surge might reach or exceed the current limit, which usually causes a voltage decrease.

Comment: @glen_geek, yes, CC limit can show this, but you will need to fish for that particular limit. A series resistor (emulating ESR) would reveal load fluctuations much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this note on size AA batteries [at this](https://www.pololu.com/blog/2/understanding-battery-capacity-ah-is-not-a) website blog. It is a large blog that clears the air about amps vs. amp/hour ratings. Based on this blog I would limit current to 500 mA. Though a Alkaline battery might be rated for 2000 to 3000 mAh, that could be a overload value and not the nominal current drain expected by the battery manufacture.

Speaking in general terms, you could expect the battery to run for about 10 hours at 10% of its mAh rating, but not all battery types follow such a drain curve, and not all loads react to a low battery the same way. Please read the blog.

> Pololu Blog » Engage Your Brain » Understanding battery capacity: Ah
>   is not A Posted by Jan on 12 November 2010
>
> AA batteries. A typical alkaline or NiMH battery in the standard “AA”
>   size has about 2000 to 3000 mAh (or 2 to 3 Ah). With a cell voltage of
>   1.2 V to 1.5V, this corresponds to 2 to 4 Wh per cell.

Comment: Capacity rating and max current capability of a cell are not directly related.

Comment: @AliChen. I should have covered that in my answer, or at least the blog itself. I never contradicted that issue, not without a disclaimer.

Comment: 12 hours at 10% of the capacity rating doesn't add up.  And unless otherwise specified, capacity ratings *are* for gentle discharges.

Comment: @ChrisStratton. Thanks for pointing that out. I have removed the confusing statement. I replaced it with "about 10 hours" to be non-specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your benchtop PSU to fully (more or less correctly) emulate AA batteries (I assume you mean alkaline AA batteries), you need to set the voltage to about 1.6 V (fresh batteries) for each cell (6.4 V total) and use an equivalent of ESR. The current limit of an AA cell depends on ESR, and ESR varies from manufacturer to manufacturer, and details of chemistry modifications.

Here is a website that has test data on some AA batteries, [Powerstream](https://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm)

Some AA cells can even hold 2 A of current (at 1 V level), making the ESR of about 150 - 200 mOhms, (crudely estimated from the data charts). This [Energizer article](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/batteryir.pdf) agrees with this estimation.

So, to emulate a 4AA battery on a benchtop PSU I would use 6.4 V voltage set point, use 1-Ohm resistor in series, and set the current threshold to about 5 A. (I just tested the short current of a AA "Kirkland Signature" battery, it comes above 8 A). To emulate discharged batteries, you would need to reduce the voltage settings.