# Which kind of AA battery should I use to power up my ESP-32

Tags: batteries, esp8266

Disclaimer : I have few knowledge in electronics

I have an ESP-32 device that use 3.3V to run perfectly. 
The 3.3V and the Ground of the device is directly connected to an AA battery container with 2 slots.

The device is a homemade sensor that use an ESP-WROOM-32 and some additional component like water detection, humidity, temperature sensors. I don't have the tools to change it. ([Datasheet of ESP-WROOM-32](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf))

Until now, I powered up my ESP-32 with 2 Alkaline Battery at 1.5V each. I was able to run it but it didn't last long (Near 20 minutes, not including deep sleep periods).

**What kind of battery should I use to power up my ESP-32 and last more than 20 minutes ?**

Comment: Maybe C-size? Or D-size? No?

Comment: My device has already the container with 2 AA Slots. I can't change it.

Comment: There is something wrong. AA alkaline batteries typically have capacity of no less than 2000 mAh. Which means delivering 2 A for an entire hour. If you depleted the batteries in 1/3 of an hour, it means that your device is consuming something like 6 A, which is very-very strange. The ESP32 consumes 240 mA typical at highest power, and the AA batteries should last several hours, unless you have some unjustifiably high voltage cut-off.

Comment: Two AAs, even new, will not deliver 3.3v. 3.2v off load is reasonable when pristine, falling quickly on load or with use. What is your endpoint voltage? To get the quoted life out of them, you need to run them down to 900mV, or 1.8v on the ESP. What's the minimum voltage it will perform to specification at? If it will work at 2.4v, then a couple of NiMH AAs would be better, they have a much flatter voltage curve as they run down.

Comment: What is your "a ESP-32 device"? What kind of on-board power regulator does it have?

Comment: @AliChen Yes, but using some functionnality like the Wifi require a lot of energie. The Alkaline battery voltage decrease with time. and after 20 minutes of wifi utilisation, my 2 batteries don't deliver enough Voltage for the Wifi

Comment: The most likely problem is that your "a ESP-32" board is not properly designed for battery-powered operation. Most likely when cell voltage drops below 1.55- V or something, your embedded regulator shuts down. So you are using maybe 10% of battery capacity.

Comment: It's this ESP http://esp32.net/images/Ai-Thinker/Other/Ai-Thinker_ESP-32S-BreakoutV1.1.jpg. Like I said,  the battery container is direcly connected to 3.3V and GND

Comment: With an ESP-WROOM-32

Comment: This is a picture of a naked PCB, with provisions to solder some MODULE. The module should contain the ESP32 QFN chip, EEPROM, crystal clock, etc. Which MODULE do you use? (Okay, I see it is WROOM module). What are the power bypass caps there?

Comment: The ESP-WROOM-32 module claims that "Power supply: 2.2 V to 3.6 V". Apparently the DFRobot overstated the capability of their product.

Comment: Use high capacity rechargeable batteries such as the Eneloop, they are much better than any of the non-rechargeable: https://metaefficient.com/rechargeable-batteries/best-rechargeable-batteries-battery-chargers.html

Comment: are you using alkaline, or "heavy duty" cheapo zinc batteries?

Comment: @JackCreasey NiMH cells such as eneloop will have lower voltage to start with.  It's possibly they might last longer around the 1.1v range, but it hasn't been confirmed what voltage the actual hardware in hand will run down to.  Absent something like a boost converter it's unclear that they'd be a suitable choice, even if in theory they might have more energy.

Comment: @Passerby I'm using Panasonic Alkaline Plus Power

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are right, and the ESP32S is 3.0 - 3.6V, so two Eneloops will not do. The OP could use two AA Nickel-zinc batteries (about 1.65V) which have very good terminal voltage hold up. These are readily available.

Comment: @JackCreasey the min supply voltage is 2.7V according to this datasheet: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: @Misunderstood The OP provided a link to the board being used ...it's a ESP-32S and is rated from 3.0 - 3.6V https://www.seeedstudio.com/ESP3212-Wifi-Bluetooth-Combo-Module-p-2706.html

Comment: @JackCreasey   The link I saw was:  http://esp32.net/images/Ai-Thinker/Other/Ai-Thinker_ESP-32S-BreakoutV1.1.jpg followed in the next comment: "With an ESP-WROOM-32"

Comment: @Misunderstood ....not worth arguing about since the OP know that 2x 1.5V cells provide only 20 mins of operating time. I'd bet the voltage is not yet below 2.7V

Comment: @JackCreasey I certainly would not "argue" with you.  Besides the OP's confusing messages regarding which product is used, I have a hard time believing he only gets 20 minutes of transmission time.  I suspect he is not using sleep mode properly.   He says the batteries last a day but is out of sleep mode for 20 minutes out of the day.  I'm happy you found the NiZn batteries, I like them.  Nice flat discharge curve.  Will probably work very well for an LED flashlight.

Comment: @Misunderstood How to not use sleep mode properly ? Maybe it's my case, I just followed the documentation and use "esp_deep_sleep_start();".

Comment: @Gazouu you are only getting 20 minutes out of a battery that should last you much longer based on the given information.   You need to constantly measure the battery voltage throughout the day to find the in circuit battery voltage at the time the device stops working.  But most of all you need to communicate more accurately.  Every user that is trying to help you is operating with a different set of parameters.  No one can help you if we do not know the minimum supply voltage required.  PUT A LINK TO THE DATASHEET OF THE EXACT ESP-32 IN YOUR POST!  What is the current draw from the battery?

Comment: @Misunderstood Edited my post with the datasheet, is there a way to mesure the battery voltage inside the arduino code ? I don't have any multimeter here

Comment: @Gazouu  I posed an answer based on the power supply requirements in the datasheet.  It's very difficult to do this stuff without proper tools.  Bottom line, you should not use AA alkaline batteries if you want more than 20 minutes.   I retract my comment about sleep mode.  I was using power requirements posted by others and not the datasheet to come to that conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the esp8266 has an input voltage range of 2.5v to 3.3v, and it is fairly power hungry, especially with the radios and peripherals all turned on. There are a couple of things you can do to extend the runtime of the device, namely:

1. Turn off the peripherals when you aren't using them. From the data sheet, the wifi uses between 50 and 200mA when it's on, which is quite a lot of power. You didn't mention what you're doing with the device, but if for instance you're making a data logging application which uploads some data to a server once a minute, then there's no reason to have the radio powered up all of the time.
2. Similar to point 1, if the micro controller isn't doing anything, there's no reason to keep it on. According to the data sheet, the micro controller uses 15mA by itself, but putting it into a light sleep uses 0.9mA, and putting it into a deep sleep uses \$20\mu A\$. Again taking the example above, there's not much of a reason to have the microcontroller powered on in between uploads of data, so if you can shut it off, do so.
3. Use a larger battery. Pretty self explanatory, using a larger battery (such as C or D cells) in place of the AA cells will give you more runtime. Additionally, you may want to consider using a lithium battery (with protection!), so when the battery does die you can recharge it instead of throwing it away.
4. Use a voltage regulator. Part of the problem you're having is that fresh alkaline batteries provide 3.0V, and by the time you've discharged them to 2.5V  the device shuts off. However, the batteries still have a lot of energy left, which can't be used by your device. To fix this, you can use a buck (step-down) converter, and use a higher voltage battery pack. For example, if you instead use a 6V battery pack (4 cells), and a buck converter that brings the voltage down to 3V for the micro, you can run the cells down to 3V before the microcontroller gives out. Alternatively, you could use a buck/boost converter which can convert the input voltage to a lower or higher voltage. Using this, you may even be able to run your 6V battery down to 1.5V, or run your 3V pack down to 1.5V, giving you more runtime.

Comment: I send data to my server every 15 minutes. And between these data transfer my ESP is in deep sleep mode as you said. For the point 3. / 4. I can't really change the hardware. The device is all in one and already have this AA battery container inside.

Comment: If your ESP (including the WiFi!) is in sleep mode for all but a short period every 15 minutes you should get much longer than 20 minutes from two AA's. Check your current consumption during sleep.

Comment: I don't count the deep sleep time in the 20 minutes. It last for less than a day including the deep sleep time

Comment: In that case it is math time. What is are contributions to the total power  consumption from the active and sleeping periods? If active, try to reduce the active period (you probably can't do much about the active current). If it is the passive period, try to reduce its power (sleep deeeper).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the buck/boost converter, I don't see a huge downside there

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the ESP-WROOM-32 module has some problem with accepting wide (dropping) range of typical AA alkaline batteries. Here is a potential solution for this problem, a [KENTLI battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SXV9Z4U). This battery uses a [Li-Ion 3.7 V battery](https://metaefficient.com/rechargeable-batteries/rechargeable-litihiumion-aa-batteries-exist.html) inside, and has a DC-DC regulator to 1.5V, thus emulating a regular AA alkaline cell. This combination should produce stable 1.5-V level until the internal battery discharges. They claim total capacity of 2800 mWh (equivalent to 1900 mAh), and it is worth to try if the ESP32 module works down to nominal 1.5 x 2 = 3.0V.

Here are the [KENTLI marketing data](http://unbatteries.com/product/show.php?id=10) on batteries,

[image]

Comment: Is the DC-DC regulator to 1.5V only present on Kentli battery ? Or if I buy any Li-Ion 3.7V Battery it would work the same ?

Comment: I just ordered 4xAA Kentli (+ their charger) from eBay for my own curiosity...

Comment: @Gazouu You can buy one 14500 Li-ion cell, and use the other AA spot to built a DC-DC switching regulator, from 4.2-3.5 V to 3.3 V. For more information on low-voltage conversion, see this exchange, electronics.stackexchange.com/a/392808/117785 . Or you can get two 14500 cells (making 8.4 to 7V range), and make a DC-DC regulator down to the same 3.3V if you have additional space. But it would require some decent engineering. The KENTLI batteries solve your problem immediately.

Comment: @Gazouu, you should try to determine voltage margins of your ESP32 module, by using a benchtop power supply. You will need to add a series resistor to emulate batteries, in case if the failure is related to heavy pulsed current during radio transmission. See this exchange for details, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/393004/117785

Comment: Interesting replacement battery.  A bit too pricey.  A NiZn battery would be much more economical and has a great discharge curve for a 3V application.  https://www.amazon.com/NiZn-2500mWh-Rechargeable-Battery-Camera/dp/B00W1DASO2/ref=sr_1_3  --- Discharge curve: http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/D600/ANS_NIZN_4XAA_DB.pdf

Comment: @Misunderstood, I agree, these NiZn cells look very good for the application, thanks. High discharge too. I probably need to order few as well.

Comment: I think they would be great for an LED flashlight where a constant voltage means constant intensity.

Answer (score 2):

Since the ESP32S module is specified at 3.0 - 3.6V operation you absolutely need a battery with a voltage **over** 1.5V.

The [Expressif design guide](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) is worth reading, the implication is that the cpu will work down to 1.8V ….but not necessarily the whole module. For example the Flash is rated at a min 2.7V.

The only choice you have for a single cell is to use two Nickel-zinc (NiZn) batteries with a terminal voltage of 1.65V.

Nickel-zinc (NiZn)

> Nickel-zinc is similar to nickel-cadmium in that it uses an alkaline
>   electrolyte and a nickel electrode, but it differs in voltage; NiZn
>   provides 1.65V/cell rather than 1.20V, which NiCd and NiMH deliver.
>   NiZn charges at a constant current to 1.9V/cell and cannot take
>   trickle charge, also known as maintenance charge. The specific energy
>   is 100Wh/kg and can be cycled 200–300 times. NiZn has no heavy toxic
>   materials and can easily be recycled. Some packaging is available in
>   the AA cell format.
>
> In 1901, Thomas Edison was awarded the U.S. patent for a rechargeable
>   nickel–zinc battery system that was installed in rail cars between
>   1932 and 1948. NiZn suffered from high self-discharge and short cycle
>   life caused by dendrite growth, which often led to an electrical
>   short. Improvements in the electrolyte have reduced this problem, and
>   NiZn is being considered again for commercial uses. Low cost, high
>   power output and good temperature operating range make this chemistry
>   attractive.

Source: [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/Nickel_based_batteries)

---

You must take care when charging, since the terminal voltage can rise above 1.8V. If you fully charge them you will exceed the rating of your module. However you can charge them to a 1.8V terminal voltage without problem.

---

Discharge Curve

[image]
source: [ANSMANN AA - 2500mWh NiZn battery Specification](http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/D600/ANS_NIZN_4XAA_DB.pdf)

Comment: Not an easy to find battery but you are correct.  A NiZn cell has the perfect discharge curve for this application.  http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/D600/ANS_NIZN_4XAA_DB.pdf

Comment: They appear to be readily available on Amazon.

Comment: I could not find a name brand supplier.  I do not like buying off brand batteries from the Amazon and eBay charlatan battery vendors.  But the OP has very limited choices being locked into AA.

Comment: Rayovac make a range, but they are relatively new in the market.

Answer (score 1):

> With an ESP-WROOM-32

If this is the [ESP-32](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf) you are using,
**you must supply at least 2.7V.**

[image]

---

**And you need a minimum of 500 mA.**

[image]

---

Two alkaline batteries cannot supply more than 2.7V @ 500 mA for very long.

If you run near 500 mA while transmitting the battery capacity is reduced to 500mAh.

So if, while transmitting, you are drawing 500 mA, you will only get about 20 minutes according to the discharge curve (shown below) for a a pair of alkaline AA batteries.  Your cutoff is 1.35V (shown in red cross hairs below) which is in the steep part at the start of the discharge curve.

**You cannot use alkaline AA batteries to power this device for more than 20 minutes if it is drawing 500 mA and 2.7V is the minimum.**

[image]
Source: [Energizer AA alkaline datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf)

Comment: You are misinterpreting the data sheet. The power supply has a minimum rating of 500mA because that is the absolute maximum current demand of the ESP32. I’ve personally never seen one hit much above 400mA, and that was an extremely brief spike. Average consumption at any given point in time is substantially less, and can be optimized down to microamps depending on the application. ESP32s do NOT have a constant current demand of 500mA minimum.